# Replacing a list of utf8 characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I have a list of Farsi characters (utf8) like this:

```
my_list = ['ﯾ', 'ﻲ', 'ﻴ']
```

And I would like to replace every occurrence of characters in this list in a text with another character like 'a'. Right now my code is like this:

```
text = text.replace('ﻴ', 'a')
text = text.replace('ﻲ', 'a')
text = text.replace('ﯾ', 'a')
```

Is there any way to do this in one shot, for example using Regex and lists in Python 3?

Comment: That's not UTF-8, at least not in Python 3.

Comment: I think they are, but even if they are not, do you know how to do what I want?

Comment: You are showing a _gylph_ (a visual representation of a character). UTF-8 is an encoding (it translates "numbers" (called code points) to letters). So what you have is a string, not "utf-8".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
3>> 'ﻴ ﻲ ﯾ'.translate({0xfbfe: 'a', 0xfef2: 'a', 0xfef4: 'a'})
'a a a'
```

[`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: Those are the [code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of the characters.

Comment: Thanks, how can I get code points of characters in Python like what you got from my characters?

Comment: `3>> hex(ord('.'))`
`'0xXXXX'`
Replace the "." with the actual character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop instead:

```
for char in my_list:
    text = text.replace(char,'a')
```

This way your list could be an arbitrary length but the size of your code wont change. Plus you aren't repeating code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not want to use `for` loop. I know that in Python using `re` it is possible to do something like I want, but I don't know how to do it with UTF-8 characters like what I have.